# Operating Systems Efficiency

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

What happens in the OS if an infinite loop is running ? Also, if an infinite loop is running and I try to start another program, would it work ? If yes, what will be the effect on the speed of the other program ?

Answer (score 2):

If your program executes in an infinite loop without context switching then one core of the machine will be tied up and unable to run anything else at the same time. Context switches happen when your code is waiting for another thread or the completion of an IO operation.
If your code is completely consuming one core like this, the operating system might still be responsive if the machine has multiple cores, and there are no other threads doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

OS remains as usual and nothing happens to it even if you are running an infinite loop, depending on what happens to three key resources of systems - CPU, Memory / RAM and Disk.

Just saying that loop is infinite is not enough, you need to also specify what kind of processing you doing in that loop.

Is it performing memory only processing and not leaving CPU free for other programs / threads ( i.e. CPU is 100% occupied) ?

Most modern systems are multi core CPU systems so most likely it will keep only one system CPU busy and rest will be free for other programs. If your loop is performing some disk I/O, it will leave even that CPU for other programs too and OS will reschedule it on different cores at different times.

Is processing continuously filling up system memory ( so eventually leading to memory being full - which will crash everything )? Or Is processing continuously filling up system memory but can fill only up to a limit ( like what happens in Java programs i.e. a fixed amount of heap memory is allocated to that program ) so program will terminate itself with out of memory error and not crash the system provided heap memory allocated is less than total system memory.

Are you writing data to disk in that loop? So eventually, disk be full and your system will crash.

So to answer this,

> Also, if an infinite loop is running and I try to start another
>   program, would it work ? If yes, what will be the effect on the speed
>   of the other program ?

It will work if there are free resources needed by new programs. Speed will be affected depending on what kind of program you are trying to start - does it need large memory, is it multi threaded and you don't have free cores? etc etc.

This is just a rough idea as what might go on due to there being infinite loop. On a side note, most of back ground services running on OS contain infinite loops but since those loops have been programmed well, we don't see any adverse side effects.